# How do I search a csv file for keywords stored in another csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to search a csv file having 150K+ row using keywords stored in a csv file with several dozen row. What's the best way to go about this? I've tried a few things but nothing has gotten me very far.

Current Code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv')
for line in data:
    if 'Apple' in line:
        print(line)
```

This isn't what I want, it's just what I currently have. The for loop is my attempt at just getting output using one of the keywords from the smaller csv file. So far I'm either getting errors or there is no output.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the large csv file I'm trying to search from is from a web link, so I don't think with open is going to work

Comment: can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I'd like to print out each row in the larger file that contains a word from the smaller one that I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your keywords are stored in a file named `keys.csv` and in each row of that file, there's only one keyword, like this:

```
Orange
Apple
...
```

then try this:

```
with open('mycsv.csv') as mycsv, open('keys.csv') as keys:
    keys = keys.readlines()
    for line in mycsv:
        if any([key[:-2] in line for key in keys]):
            print(line)
```

Comment: I tried this method but with open doesn't seem to work for web links. What method would work for a csv file downloaded from GitHub opened on a webpage?